# What is the impact of switching in and out of the PHP render engine?

Tags: php

Is there a substantial impact in performance (both in the browser and on the server) by exiting and entering the PHP render engine?  Example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum..</p>

<?php
myPHPfunction();
?>

<p>more html</p>

<?php
anotherPHPfunction();
?>
```

If this is a big impact in terms of performance, how can I bundle all of the PHP up together, especially if the majority of my pages are static HTML?

Comment: I don't know about performance issue, but it shouldn't affect IMO. And if you really need to add logic to your views, try to make the logic code look nicer :) Use <?php foreach(...):?> instead of <php foreach (...) {?> for example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of performance, there really isn't a downside of doing this. When you use these echo statements, PHP is building an internal ouput buffer that will eventually get flushed to the browser once the page is done executing. There are ways around this, such as [`ob_flush`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php).

**However** in terms of [separation of concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and overall software design, it is bad to put business logic(NOT view logic as Brenton pointed out below) with your views. Your code becomes harder to maintain if you have this type of setup.

Comment: Don't confuse "business logic" with "view logic" however or you can still end up with a mess due to too many layers of abstraction. Things like looping over a list to create a table or formatting a price in $##.## format are view logic and there is no need to separate them from the html (though you may still create "helper" functions so you don't have to repeat yourself or to avoid large chunks of logic in your HTML).

Comment: This is basically what I would have said. There may be some very small performance hit, but if you're at the point where that performance hit matters to you, you have bigger fish to fry and there are better ways to optimize your code than trying to optimize when you're turning the rendering engine on and off. And +1 for separation of business logic and the view (another great reason to use a framework like CodeIgniter).